# Update table with no data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I un-select all my check boxes it and submit form. It should clear that permissions column matching group id. It does not. It updates fine if some `$data['permissions']` are there but need it to clear column if I unselect all and submit form.

But for some reason `permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . "` will not work `: ''`

**Throws error.**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE user_group_id = '10'' at line 5 UPDATE user_group SET name
>   = 'Demonstration', permission = WHERE user_group_id = '10' Filename: C:/Xampp/htdocs/codeigniter-3/application/modules/admin/models/user/model_user_user_group.php
>   Line Number: 19

**Model Function**

```
public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group 
        SET 
        name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
        permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . "
        WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "'
    ");
}
```

**Whats wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved problem, I have had to use escape quotes `"''"`

```
permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : "''") . "
```

Model

```
public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data) {
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group 
        SET 
        name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
        permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : "''") . "
        WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "'
    ");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

at the end of your function so that you can check what query have been executed.